# Show Progress Bar when link to Document a file is clicked

Tags: html, angular

I want to implement a progress bar when the link to download a file from a server is clicked. See below the HTML snippet. I need help with the implementation of this.

```
 <a *ngIf="editing" title="Download document" id="downloadLink"
                    (click)="downloadDocument(myDocument.id, myDocument.attachedName)">{{nameAttached}} </a>
```

Download method in Typescript

```
       downloadDocument(id: number, attachedName: string) {
       this.loadingDocumentFileId = id;
       this.newCustomerDocumentService.downloadDocument(id, attachedName);
       setTimeout(() => {
        this.loadingDocumentFileId = null;
    }, 4000);
  }
```

Comment: so what is not working?

Comment: how to go about getting the progress Bar when I click the Download file.

Comment: Do you need loading indicator or progress bar (file download process)?

Comment: Either way, it will be perfect. Preferably loading indicator, please.

Comment: Okay can you provide me a sample demo? will try with that?